# Template inheritance: Symbol not found

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, linker, rcpp

I'm having problems with templates & inheritance.  I've whittled down some problematic code to something I can post here.  My code is as follows:

```
///////////////////////////// My header.h file
#include <vector>

template <class T>
class Slider {
protected:
  std::vector<T> out;
public:
  Slider() : out() {}
  virtual void save_result();
};

template <class T>
class SlidingVar : public Slider<T> {
public:
  SlidingVar() {}
  void save_result() {}
};

template <class T>
void slide(std::vector<T> x, Slider<T> s) {}

///////////////////////////// My sliding_sd.cpp file
#include <vector>
#include "headers.h"

void sliding_var_window(std::vector<double> x) {
  SlidingVar<double> s;
  slide(x, s);
}
```

Although the above is all "pure C++" code, I'm doing this in the context of an `R` package for which my `sliding_var_window` function will be exported to be callable from R.

The above compiles okay, but when R loads it using `dlopen`, I get `Symbol not found` errors about the `save_result()` function.  Oddly, before I whittled this down, other similar functions were working just fine, but not this one.  Here's the build sequence:

```
==> R CMD INSTALL --preclean --no-multiarch --with-keep.source tsevents

* installing to library ‘/Users/kwilliams/R/library/3.4’
* installing *source* package ‘TSEvents’ ...
** libs
clang++ -std=gnu++11 -I/usr/local/Cellar/r/3.4.2/lib/R/include -DNDEBUG  -I"/Users/kwilliams/R/library/3.4/Rcpp/include" -I/usr/local/opt/gettext/include -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include -I/usr/local/include   -fPIC  -g -O2 -c sliding_sd.cpp -o sliding_sd.o
clang++ -std=gnu++11 -dynamiclib -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names -undefined dynamic_lookup -single_module -multiply_defined suppress -L/usr/local/opt/gettext/lib -L/usr/local/opt/readline/lib -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/local/Cellar/r/3.4.2/lib/R/lib -L/usr/local/opt/gettext/lib -L/usr/local/opt/readline/lib -L/usr/local/lib -o TSEvents.so sliding_sd.o -L/usr/local/Cellar/r/3.4.2/lib/R/lib -lR -lintl -Wl,-framework -Wl,CoreFoundation
installing to /Users/kwilliams/R/library/3.4/TSEvents/libs
** R
** preparing package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** testing if installed package can be loaded
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘TSEvents’ in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...):
 unable to load shared object '/Users/kwilliams/R/library/3.4/TSEvents/libs/TSEvents.so':
  dlopen(/Users/kwilliams/R/library/3.4/TSEvents/libs/TSEvents.so, 6): Symbol not found: __ZN6SliderIdE11save_resultEv
  Referenced from: /Users/kwilliams/R/library/3.4/TSEvents/libs/TSEvents.so
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in /Users/kwilliams/R/library/3.4/TSEvents/libs/TSEvents.so
Error: loading failed
```

I suspect this really has nothing to do with `R` or `Rcpp`, but that's providing my build environment, so if someone could suggest a way to demonstrate this problem in a pure C++ toolchain, that would be most welcome.

Another tidbit I don't understand - when I look at the symbols defined in the object file, the `save_result()` function appears to have an `unsigned short` return type, when I declared it to be `void`:

```
% nm src/TSEvents.so | c++filt | grep result
0000000000002df0 unsigned short SlidingVar<double>::save_result()
                 U Slider<double>::save_result()
```

Is that normal?

Comment: Can you make it an actual 'minimally reproducible example'?

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel I can now that Fabian showed me how to - is it better to strip out the (large) irrelevant R/Rcpp sections, or add a reprex at the end as an addition?

Comment: BTW the `U` in your `nm ... | c++filt` output was already a smoking gun as it mean _undefined_ -- see `man nm`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could reproduce the linker error after adding an `int main() { }` and compiling with `g++` without additional options:

```
sliding_sd.cpp:(.rdata$_ZTV6SliderIdE[__ZTV6SliderIdE]+0x8): undefined reference to `Slider<double>::save_result()'
```

This means there is a reference to the virtual method `Slider<double>::save_result()` in the vtable (virtual method table) of `Slider<double>` which could not be resolved during linking. The cause is that you declared `save_result()` in `template <class T> class Slider` but did not define it (at least in the code you have posted). Albeit `Slider<double>::save_result()` is never used in your example, it must be defined (at least when using ordinary C++, I do not know about R), as it is `virtual`. Otherwise the vtable for `Slider<double>` cannot be created during linking.

When changed to

```
template <class T>
class Slider {
  /* ... */
  virtual void save_result() { }
};
```

the linking error disappears (at least in my reproduction).

Comment: Thanks!  I’ll give this a try. My intention is to declare this as a virtual method that must be overridden, would `= 0;` be another sensible alternative?

Comment: I also thought of `= 0;`, but this causes an `invalid abstract parameter type 'Slider<double>'` compiler error, as `slide` has an argument of type `Slider<T>` and this is not allowed when `Slider<T>` has a pure (`= 0`) virtual member function. But when you pass the argument by reference, i.e. `template <class T>
void slide(std::vector<T> x, Slider<T>& s) {}`, you may use `= 0;`.

Comment: After trying this out, here's an important note: passing the `Slider` by reference is essential for the method dispatch to work correctly.  If I don't add the `&`, then the base `Slider` method gets called rather than the desired method in the derived `SlidingVar` class.

Comment: Yes, I should have mentioned (but probably was distracted by the linking problem): Dynamic dispatch of `virtual` methods requires that the object be accessed by reference (`&`) or by pointer (`*`), with the first option usually being more convenient and preferable. When declared as a (class) type without reference or pointer in a function, the argument is (if necessary) converted to the declared type and that means all members are those of the declared type (when accessed from within the function).